# speech recognition stopped if i did not say something, how to keep it listening

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Wanted to create 2 buttons one to start the speech recognition and keep on until i click on the button finish. the issue is when i click start and did not say something its stopped :

```
import tkinter as tk
import speech_recognition as sr

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Voice to Text")
window.geometry("300x350")

def startvoice():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("speak now")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        startvoice.voice2text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("you said:{}".format(startvoice.voice2text))
    except:
        print("Your voice not clear")

def finished():
    text_field.focus()
    text_field.delete('1.0', tk.END)
    text_field.insert('1.0', startvoice.voice2text)

text_field = tk.Text(master=window, height=20, width=40)
text_field.grid(column=0, row=2)


button1 = tk.Button(text="Start", width=16, command=startvoice)
button1.grid(column=0, row=0)

button1 = tk.Button(text="finish", width=16, command=finished)
button1.grid(column=0, row=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the `listen` method has a timeout parameter that is probably what you are looking for, e.g.

```
audio = r.listen(source, timeout=60)
```

would allow you a minute before giving up.